# C# warning: "The variable is assigned but its value is never used"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, while-loop, compiler-warnings

I am a first-timer learning C# and I just started writing my first program. I am currently running into a snag in one of my while loops. Normally I find that outside the loop my variables work like they should, but for some reason Visual Studio is giving me a warning saying that "The variable 'itemPrice' is assigned but its value is never used."

How I can I get that warning to go away and avoid any kind of bad practices?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        // "whoa" <-- string literal
        // 43 <-- int literal
        // 43.34 <-- double literal
        // false <-- bool literal
        // 43.4f <-- float literal
        // 43f <-- float literal
        // 43m <-- decimal literal

        bool hasEnteredMoney = false;
        decimal money = 0;
        int menuSelection;
        decimal itemPrice;
        bool isValidItem;
        string itemName;

        while (!hasEnteredMoney)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter how much money you have: ");
            hasEnteredMoney = decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out money);

            if (!hasEnteredMoney)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid decimal value.");
            }
        }

        while (money >= 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have $" + money + " left.");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your selection:");
            Console.WriteLine("[0] - Poke Ball - $200");
            Console.WriteLine("[1] - Great Ball - $700");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] - Ultra Ball - $1200");
            Console.WriteLine("[3] - Potion - $300");
            Console.WriteLine("[4] - Antidote - $100");
            Console.WriteLine("[5] - Clear Mail - $50");
            Console.WriteLine(": ");

            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menuSelection))
            {

                isValidItem = false;

                if (menuSelection == 0)
                {
                    itemPrice = 200;
                    itemName = "Poke Ball";
                    isValidItem = true;
                }

                if (menuSelection == 1)
                {
                    itemPrice = 700;
                    itemName = "Great Ball";
                    isValidItem = true;
                }

                if (menuSelection == 2)
                {
                    itemPrice = 1200;
                    itemName = "Ultra Ball";
                    isValidItem = true;
                }

                if (menuSelection == 3)
                {
                    itemPrice = 300;
                    itemName = "Potion";
                    isValidItem = true;
                }

                if (menuSelection == 4)
                {
                    itemPrice = 100;
                    itemName = "Antidote";
                    isValidItem = true;
                }

                if (menuSelection == 5)
                {
                    itemPrice = 50;
                    itemName = "Clear Mail";
                    isValidItem = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("... you ran out of money :(");

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the variable in question?

Comment: What are you doing with the variable `money`. Once it is assigned, it doesn't change anywhere in the code. The loop: `while (money >= 3)` will run endlessly

Comment: Or possibly the loop will never run at all.

Answer (score 1):

The variables `itemPrice, isValidItem, itemName` are being set (being assigned to), but the variables are not being used for other purposes later in the program.

The compiler is warning you that although you are setting `itemPrice, isValidItem`, and `itemName`, setting these variables is not doing anything in the program - E.G. when the program is executed, the variables will not have any effect on the operation of the program.

Answer (score 0):

It is giving you this error because your variables are never use in the code.

```
itemPrice = 200;
itemName = "Poke Ball";
isValidItem = true;
```

So visual studio intellisense is basicly saying : you putting all those values in your variables, but are never using any of them no where.

If you  `Console.WriteLine(itemName);` at the end of you code, the warning should go away for all the itemName in you loop.

tl;dr You `set;` them but never `get;` them

Answer (score -1):

The warning is a good indication that you should actually do something with the value.  In your case, I think you would want to do something like

```
money -= itemPrice;
```

First, it will get rid of the warning.

Second, it will keep the while loop from running indefinitely :)